# In dwarf fortress, how can I use reactions or dfhack to make my adventurer a vampire?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I enjoy screwing around, and becoming a vampire makes that much easier but it becomes tiring finding one to kill for each new adventurer I make.

Comment: Sorry my response isn't exactly what you're looking for. If I find out the other information I'll add it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the command is in dfhack, but according to [the wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Vampire) as of v42, you can become either a vampire or werewolf by toppling statues:

> **Becoming a vampire by toppling statues**
>
> As of v42 it is now additionally possible to become a vampire by toppling statues in a temple or sanctuary.
>
> Walk up to the statue and topple it with u then a. Toppling a statue in this way will lead you to being cursed: the curse will be either Vampirism or Werebeast. Which curse you get appears to be randomly decided at the time you topple the statue (reloading the game and toppling it again has been confirmed to give the alternate curse.)